# SilverlightControl cannot be found when parent is an HtmlCustom control during coded ui playback

Tags: silverlight, automation, coded-ui-tests

I am hand coding CodedUI tests for a WebApp.  The web app is approximately 50% silverlight.  I have a HtmlCustom control that searches the webpage for my parent object.  It is then used to create a SilverlightControl for the main page template.  The page template has an ID associated with it also.  I have this code in other areas of the web app and it works fine but for some reason it does not here.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Parent of UIControlViewPlaylistsXAP
    /// </summary>
    private HtmlCustom mUICustomViewPlaylistsXAP;
    private HtmlCustom UICustomViewPlaylistsXAP
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.mUICustomViewPlaylistsXAP == null)
            {
                this.mUICustomViewPlaylistsXAP = new HtmlCustom(this);
                this.mUICustomViewPlaylistsXAP.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlCustom.PropertyNames.Id, "viewPlaylistsObject");
                this.mUICustomViewPlaylistsXAP.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlCustom.PropertyNames.TagName, "OBJECT");
                this.mUICustomViewPlaylistsXAP.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlCustom.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition, "data=\"data:application/x-oleobject;base64", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);
            }
            return this.mUICustomViewPlaylistsXAP;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parent of all direct Page: View Playlists controls
    /// </summary>
    private SilverlightControl mUIControlViewPlaylistsXAP;
    public SilverlightControl UIControlViewPlaylistsXAP
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.mUIControlViewPlaylistsXAP == null)
            {
                this.mUIControlViewPlaylistsXAP = new SilverlightControl(this.UICustomViewPlaylistsXAP);
                this.mUIControlViewPlaylistsXAP.SearchProperties.Add(SilverlightControl.PropertyNames.AutomationId, "VisiconnPageTemplate");
                ////this.mUIControlViewPlaylistsXAP.SearchProperties.Add(SilverlightControl.PropertyNames.MaxDepth, "-1");
                this.mUICustomViewPlaylistsXAP.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
                //// this.mUIControlViewPlaylistsXAP.SearchProperties.Add(SilverlightControl.PropertyNames.ControlType, "VisiconnPageTemplate");

             }
            return this.mUIControlViewPlaylistsXAP;
        }
    }
```

So mUIControlViewPlaylists.XAP comes back with UITestControlNotFoundException which has the AutomationId associated with it.  If there are any ideas on a better way of doing this or the problem in general they would be surely appreciated.